# How can I activate the specific nav from header while scrolling to the corresponding section in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a sticky header component that has a navbar

```
<header id="header" class="header" id='header' #header>
   <div class="header__nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a routerLink='/' fragment = 'producer'> producer </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a routerLink='/' fragment = 'consumer'>
                    consumer 
                 </a>
            </li>   
       </ul>
    </div> 
</header>
```

I have another component that has a producer and consumer section.

```
<section #producer id='producer'>
.....
</section>
<section #consumer id='consumer'>
.....
</section>
```

I want to activate the producer in the navbar when I scroll to the producer section. And activate the consumer in the navbar when I scroll to the consumer section. How can I achieve that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create our own directive. Suppose we have the following markup.

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': currentSection === 'section1'}">section 1</div>
  <div class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': currentSection === 'section2'}">section 2</div>
  <div class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': currentSection === 'section3'}">section 3</div>
  <div class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': currentSection === 'section4'}">section 4</div>
  <div class="nav-link" [ngClass]="{'active': currentSection === 'section5'}">section 5</div>
</div>
<div sectionScroll (sectionChange)="onSectionChange($event)">
  <div id="section1" class="section"> 
    Section 1
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="section"> 
    Section 2
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="section"> 
    Section 3
  </div>
  <div id="section4" class="section"> 
    Section 4
  </div>
  <div id="section5" class="section"> 
    Section 5
  </div>
</div>
```

And the component itself:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  currentSection = 'section1';

  constructor() {}

  onSectionChange(sectionId: string) {
    this.currentSection = sectionId;
  }
}
```

There's a directive in the parent block that we will be looking at below and sectionChange that calls the method onSectionChange only when the directive onSectionChange sends a value. There's a unique ID for each section which is needed in order to determine the current active section within the directive. The directive itself looks as follows.

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  EventEmitter,
  HostListener,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[sectionScroll]',
})
export class SectionScrollDirective {
  private spiedTags = ['DIV'];

  @Output() public sectionChange = new EventEmitter<string>();
  private currentSection!: string;

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('document:mousewheel', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event: any) {
    let currentSection = '';
    const childrens = this._el.nativeElement.children;
    const top = event.target.scrollTop;
    const parentOffset = event.target.offsetTop;
    for (let i = 0; i < childrens.length; i++) {
      const element = childrens[i];
      if (this.spiedTags.some((spiedTag) => spiedTag === element.tagName)) {
        if (element.offsetTop - parentOffset <= top) {
          currentSection = element.id;
        }
      }
    }
    if (currentSection !== this.currentSection) {
      this.currentSection = currentSection;
      this.sectionChange.emit(this.currentSection);
    }
  }
}
```

The array spiedTags stores the tag names which we will be tracking.

Using HostListener (see https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener), we listen to the scroll event on the element to which the directive is attached to. Every time the scroll event is triggered, the onScroll method is called that goes through the elements of the array with child elements of the element to which the directive is attached and determines the element that crosses the top part of the browser window and after that assigns a unique identifier to currentSection that we determined in the template for each section. After that we check that if the section has changed, then we have to send a new section's value from the directive.

currentSection within the component is required in order to determine which reference in navbar will be used to assign the active class to using the directive ngClass.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know of any clean out of the box solution. However, you could use intersection observers to detect the visibility of the sections and append/update the fragment. To activate it in the navbar, the `routerLinkActive` directive with `routerLinkActiveOptions` setting `fragment: 'exact'` can be utilized.

Look at this [blog post](https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/enhancing-multi-pane-single-page-web-apps-with-intersection-observer-5929e2c0c6b) which addresses an issue similar to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed using the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is a good idea. This way you can trigger a callback e.g `service.updateHeader(target.id)` when the target element is in view - which can then update your `<a>` links.

Example with three components and one service.

- to hold the scrollable stuff
- one is the header
- one will be the child of the scrollable container area, so your `section` elements

  ```
   export class ScrollerComponent implements AfterViewInit {

     @ViewChild('sec') sec: SectionsComponent;

     constructor(private toggleHeaderService: ToggleHeaderActiveService) {}

     ngAfterViewInit() {
       const options = {
         root: null,
         rootMargin: '0px',
         threshold: 1.0,
       };

     const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
       entries.forEach(entry => {
         entry.isIntersecting && this.toggleHeaderService.updateHeader(entry.target.id);
       });
     }, options);

     const elementsToObserve = [this.sec.producer.nativeElement, this.sec.consumer.nativeElement];
     elementsToObserve.forEach(e => {
       observer.observe(e);
     });
   }
  }
  ```

scroller-component.html

```
<app-sections #sec></app-sections>
```

Pass default options to the InstersectionObserver, `root: null` means it uses the viewport as container root. Target your child component where the native HTML is using `@ViewChild`.

Then target your `sections` as `ElementRef` via `@ViewChild` on the child component also - this one exposes the raw DOM native elements.
Once your targets are set, when those elements pass into the viewport, the service call is triggered. This happens with the `entry.isIntersecting` flag which will execute the service call if `true`. This [article](https://medium.com/@nicolasmarcora/mastering-javascripts-and-logical-operators-fd619b905c8f) describes functions in logical`&&` operators.

In the intersection function pass the element that was triggered to the service as `entry.target.id`. Then finally read these from your sticky header to activate whichever id was triggered.

```
export class SectionsComponent {

  @ViewChild('producer') producer: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('consumer') consumer: ElementRef;
}
```

.sections-component.html

```
<section #consumer id="consumer">
  consumer stuff...</section>

  <div>other html...</div>
 
<section #producer id="producer">
  producer stuff...</section>
```

toggle.service.ts

```
export class ToggleHeaderActiveService {

  private activeRoute = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  readonly getActiveRoute = this.activeRoute.asObservable();

  public updateHeader(pc: string) {
    this.activeRoute.next(pc);
  }
}
```

Finally, header.ts - where you read.

```
export class StickyHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  producer = false;
  consumer = false;

  constructor(private toggleService: ToggleHeaderActiveService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toggleService.getActiveRoute
      .pipe(
        tap( it => {
          this.producer = it === 'producer';
          this.consumer = it === 'consumer';
        })
      ).subscribe( );
  }
}
```

header.html

```
<header id="header" class="header"  #header>
  <div class="header__nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a routerLink='/' [ngClass]="{'active':producer}"> producer </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a routerLink='/' [ngClass]="{'active':consumer}">consumer</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

header.scss

```
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

The options that you pass to the `IntersectionObserver` can be fine-tuned at a granular level according to what you want. But this is the just of the pattern.